# How to show that $\{a^p ~|~ p\text{ is not prime}\}$ is not a CFL?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, context-free, pumping-lemma

I want to show that the language $L=\{a^p ~|~ p\text{ is not prime}\}$ is not a CFL.

If I look at $\bar{L}=\{a^p ~|~ p\text{ is prime}\}$, it is pretty straightforward to show that it is not a CFL with the pumping lemma, by choosing the word $w=a^p$, and with $w_{p+1}=a^{p+sp}=a^{p(1+s)}\notin L$ because $p(1+s)$ is not a prime number.

But what word do I have to choose to prove that $L$ is not a CFL?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $\{ a^c \mid c \text{ is composite}\}$ is not regular using Dirichlet's theorem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/151184/show-that-ac-mid-c-text-is-composite-is-not-regular-using-dirichlet). Although the question is about regular languages, the proof in accepted answer also shows that $L$ is not context-free.

Comment: A unary language (a subset of $a^*$) is context-free iff it is regular.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Interesting! Thank you!